# How does Jira confluence software talk to Github server?

Tags: github, authorization, jira, jira-rest-api, confluence

So, As github is deprecating authorization through `access_token` query param, we were sent a mail from github that a call has been made with access_token in query param and were asked to update things to include authorization info in request headers.

We are suspecting that the api call is made from Jira confluence app from the github integration that was done by admin which we don't have control over.

So, just trying to debug things here. Does anyone know how Jira confluence internally communicates with Github servers using access_token to update pull requests and commits etc in Jira tickets?

If this is not the correct domain for this please move it to the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very possibly the Github/Jira integration. This [bug ticket](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSWSERVER-20414) was resolved in August but based on the comments there it's not completely fixed or released.

[This issue](https://github.com/integrations/jira/issues/311) has some back-and-forth but [this comment](https://github.com/integrations/jira/issues/311#issuecomment-706176895) clears things up: it looks like GitHub recommends uninstalling the old Jira integration and using the one GitHub maintains instead.